# Retrieving data for a form from a service

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have forms that make AJAX calls for data like below:

```
 $.ajax({ url: "/adminTasks/GetJsonDSData",
          data: { ABC: "Abc" },
          success: function (data) {

 etc.
```

The calls work fine but add to the code in my controllers. I would like to move the methods behind these calls outside of the controllers but I am not sure how to do this. Seems like all the calls must be routed to a URL of a controller.

I had the idea to move the methods into helper classes in my storage project. This works fine and now I can have the action go to the controller which then calls the storage methods and which then returns data to the controller.

Is there any way I can take the controllers out of the loop to simplify things?

Comment: Why do you want to get rid of the controller? You could set up web services instead but what's making you want to take the controller out of the loop?

Comment: Why do you want to use MVC if you don't want the "C"?

Comment: I want to bypass the controller for code involved in the retrieval of JSON data. This code significantly adds to the bulk of the controller and there are routines for getting data that I need to duplicate in different controllers.

Comment: The code for obtaining the data should not be in your controller. If you're duplicating code then you're probably doing something askew. Data retreival should be in the service layer and the controller should be serving this data as JSON to the front end.

Comment: Also, if you don't want all the Json methods in the adminTasks controller, what's stopping you putting them in a more relvant controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is to make sure that all code related to obtaining data from the datbase is in your service layer.

Your controller will be making calls to the service to receive specific data for the purpose of sending it to the front end.

If you feel that you have too many JSON methods in your adminTasks controller I recommend you move them to a more appropriate controller.

Comment: So are you saying to create another controller that's not related to the view?  Something like a jsonDataController?

Comment: Your View is your JSON data is it not? You don't have a seperate view other than the retuned data do you?

Comment: Or are you refering to the view on which you present the loaded JSON data? The views you have are not bound to any single controller or controller method. Any controller method can return any view. So the view and the controller are not tightly bound in the way you make it sound. If the JSON methods are directly related to your adminTasks controller, then keep them there (put them in a partial class if you want to keep things neat [I wouldn't do this though, it seems pointless]).